# Atualizar usuário Devise via API com segurança

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Em uma app eu preciso editar os dados cadastrais de um usuário como nome, email, telefone e a senha(para a senha opcional, encontrei essa [solução](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)).

Porém esta alteração é feita via API. Já que envolve alteração de dados eu preciso saber como fazer essa alteração com segurança. Se fosse apenas na web usaria o current_user o que me garantiria que apenas o usuário logado alteraria seus próprios dados. Mas neste caso não sei como funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que você faça uma abordagem com um `TOKEN` para autenticação de usuário via API (note que não está relacionado com o antigo TokenAuthenticable do Devise).

Seu model User vai ter um `TOKEN` que será um código randômico. A cada requisição da API você passa esse `TOKEN` para garantir que é o usuário verdadeiro.

O rails já tem um método para verificar esse tipo de autenticação: `authenticate_with_http_token`

Caso queira aumentar a segurança você pode também fornecer um `APP_SECRET` que será usado para codificar o seu token, através de um algoritmo.

Esse `APP_SECRET` não vai ser enviado na comunicação (chamadas HTTP), mas tem que estar guardado tanto no servidor quanto no cliente.

Referências que podem te ajudar:

http://blog.envylabs.com/post/75521798481/token-based-authentication-in-rails
http://keighl.com/post/secure-api-request-from-ios-to-rails/